# How to ace.js Editor remove red space dot?

Tags: c#, ace-editor

First, Sorry. but I don't speak English well.
but i think you understand me.

[image]

only c# code happend. other languege is normal

red background dot tag here

```
<span class="ace_invisible ace_invisible_space ace_invalid">·</span>
```

in first line create this tag. why this happening?
i wondering that. and how to work out?

just so you know i changed latest release version.
I really want to thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you right click it and select inspect? That might tell you more.

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57287558/8444504

Comment: @khobalt <span class="ace_invisible ace_invisible_space ace_invalid">·</span> here. i modified.